Central Limit Theorem for Bounded Random Vectors with Dependency Graphs
I am familiar with the following Central Limit Theorem (CLT) result for a family of bounded random variables with a dependency graph structure (Paper Link):
Let $\{Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{d}\}$ be a family of bounded random variables, i.e., $|Y_{i}| \leq A$ for $i \in [d]$. Suppose that $\Gamma_{d}$ is a dependency graph for this family, where each node represents a random variable $Y_i$ and an edge exists between nodes $i$ and $j$ if $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are dependent. Let $M$ be the maximal degree of $\Gamma_{d}$ (if $\Gamma_{d}$ has no edges, we set $M=1$). Define $S_{d} := \sum_{i=1}^d Y_{i}$ and $\sigma_{d}^2 = Var(S_d)$. If there exists an integer $\alpha$ such that
$$
\lim_{d \to \infty} \left(\frac{d}{M}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \frac{M A}{\sigma_{d}} = 0,
$$
then
$$
\frac{S_d - E[S_d]}{\sigma_d} \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0, 1) \text{ as } d \rightarrow \infty.
$$
I am wondering if a similar result exists for random vectors instead of random variables. Specifically, if $\{\mathbf{Y}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{Y}_d\}$ are bounded random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$, i.e., $\|\mathbf{Y}_i\| \leq A$ for all $i$, and $\Gamma_d$ is a dependency graph with the same structure (each node represents a random vector $\mathbf{Y}_i$ and an edge exists between nodes $i$ and $j$ if $\mathbf{Y}_i$ and $\mathbf{Y}_j$ are dependent), can we obtain a CLT for the sum $\mathbf{S}_d := \sum_{i=1}^d \mathbf{Y}_i$ with appropriate normalization?
I would appreciate any insights or references to results that extend the CLT to random vectors with dependency graph structures.

The standard approach is the the Cramér-Wold device. Write $r_d$ for the normalising sequence, then $$r_d(S_d-E[S_d])\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,V)$$
if and only if
$$r_d(b'S_d-E[b'S_d])\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,b'Vb)$$
for every unit $k$-vector $b$. This reduces the problem from a vector limit to a set of scalar limits. The maximal degree is unchanged and the boundedness transfers from $S$ to $b'S$, as do the variances
